# How to insert blank line using Linux Shell Script together with Python Script?

Tags: python, linux, shell, io

I'm currently redirecting a Python Script Output to a Log file (log) in Linux

Python Script Example (example.py):

```
print("output")
```

Shell script:

```
python3 example.py >> log
```

When I check log content (`cat log`) after running example.py a few times, I get:

```
output
output
output
```

So, I'd like to add a blank line before the next "output" entry. The wanted position is:

```
output

output

output
```

What should I do in the Shell Script differently in order to achieve so (not editting example.py)?

Thanks

---

Update:

example.py:

```
print("output1")
print("output2")
```

When running a first time `python3 example.py | sed 's/$/\n/' >> log`, I get:

```
output1

output2
```

When running it a second time:

```
output1

output2

output1

output2
```

I need to achieve:

```
output1
output2

output1
output2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `echo` after your script finishes executing to add a trailing newline:

```sh
(python3 example.py; echo) >> log
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran your suggestion ('python3 example.py | sed 's/$/\n/' >> log'), however, my original file prints out more than 1 line to the log file. I could notice that the "sed" statement adds 1 blank line after each of the my print results. Is there a way to add a blank line just after the end of all the print results? I updated my original question in order to ilustrate that. Thanks

Comment: @Nunes I've edited my answer so it should work now.

Comment: You can use `{}` to avoid spawning a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is :

```
python3 example.py >> log && echo >> log
```

This will append the output from the python script and **after** that append an extra blank line.

If you want to append an extra blank line **before** each output of the python script :

```
echo >> log && python3 example.py >> log
```

This will append a blank line and then the output of the python script.